# Etymology of "Seasoned" (experienced) --- salt or Summer?

Tags: etymology

Hey just curious explaining "seasoned" as in veteran to a non-English speaker.

Like "he's a seasoned golf player."

I can't seem to find answers on Google.

Does "seasoned" derive from a food dish "seasoned" --- meaning the guy has been around, so he's been honed and colored through time?

Or is it more "seasoned" --- he's seen many seasons (fall, winter, spring ... years) of X activity?

Just curious.

Comment: You can have salty, sugary or spicy manner, without being experienced.

Comment: The second one,  "experienced many seasons".  The etymology of "seasoned" meaning "with salt, pepper, spices etc" also comes from this, and with a meaning similar to "ripened".

Comment: The fact that the "seasoned food" and "experienced many seasons" senses do not contradict one another is a good example of how metaphors (and proverbs, and myths, and stories) work. _Seasoned veteran_ works with **both** senses, so it doesn't matter which one people use; the more the merrier, as long as it's understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably derives from Old French *assaisoner* (to ripen).
By extension  applied to a mature, experienced person.

***[To season:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/season)***

> “Improving flavor by adding spices” from Old French *assaisoner* to ripen, season, on the notion of fruit becoming more palatable as it ripens. Applied to timber by 1540s."

(Etymonline)

Comment: Ah very interesting. Thanks! Makes sense that they come from the same place really.

Comment: I've always thought that it was related to the idea of "seasoned timber" which is wood that has been properly dried out so that it does not warp see [this commercial webpage](https://whitmores.co.uk/hardwood-timber-seasoning-explained/) for example.